# Real memory usage increases 2x when I load a texture in OpenGLES

Tags: iphone, memory, opengl-es, textures

I've been banging my head against this one for a while.  The situation is this:  I've made a 2D game for iphone on my own little OpenGL 2D game engine (which I built as an experiment but which may now actually ship).  I'm trying to get memory under control.  I'm using texture atlases, and I'm familiar with PVRTC (but as of now I'm not using it).  The issue is that if I load a 1024x1024 png texture atlas, which I expect to take about 4 megs when expanded into memory (1024 x 1024 x 4 bytes per pixel - RBGA8888  =  4 megs), the real memory usage (according to Instruments-Memory Monitor) increases by 8 megs.  Aaagh!

I'm aware that OpenGLES takes the texture data, expands it into memory, then reorders the pixels to work on the PowerVR chip, and then makes a texture out of it (or something similar). Is it possible that this memory is not getting freed?  So that I have two copies of each texture sitting around in memory? From the ObjectiveC side of things, I see everything releasing correctly.  But what goes on behind the OpenGL API, I don't know. I'm probably missing something.

My implementation for loading the textures I got from O'Reilly's iPhone Game Development book.  Here are the key points I'm using for implementation:

Step 1 - get image data to correct (power of 2) size:

```
- (id) initWithImage:(UIImage *)uiImage
{
    NSUInteger            width, height, i;
    CGContextRef          context = nil;
    void*                 data = nil;
    CGColorSpaceRef       colorSpace;
    void*                 tempData;
    unsigned int*         inPixel32;
    unsigned short*       outPixel16;
    BOOL                  hasAlpha;
    CGImageAlphaInfo      info;
    CGAffineTransform     transform;
    CGSize                imageSize;
    GLTexturePixelFormat  pixelFormat;
    CGImageRef            image;
    UIImageOrientation    orientation;
    BOOL                  sizeToFit = NO;

    image = [uiImage CGImage];
    orientation = [uiImage imageOrientation]; 

    if(image == NULL) {
        [self release];
        NSLog(@"Image is Null");
        return nil;
    }


    info = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(image);
    hasAlpha = ((info == kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast) || (info == kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst) || (info == kCGImageAlphaLast) || (info == kCGImageAlphaFirst) ? YES : NO);
    if(CGImageGetColorSpace(image)) {
        if(hasAlpha)
            pixelFormat = kGLTexturePixelFormat_RGBA8888;
        else
            pixelFormat = kGLTexturePixelFormat_RGB565;
    } else { //NOTE: No colorspace means a mask image
        pixelFormat = kGLTexturePixelFormat_A8;
    }

    imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image));
    transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    width = imageSize.width;
    if((width != 1) && (width & (width - 1))) {
        i = 1;
        while((sizeToFit ? 2 * i : i) < width)
        i *= 2;
        width = i;
    }

    height = imageSize.height;
    if((height != 1) && (height & (height - 1))) {
        i = 1;
        while((sizeToFit ? 2 * i : i) < height)
        i *= 2;
        height = i;
    }

    while((width > kMaxTextureSize) || (height > kMaxTextureSize)) {
        width /= 2;
        height /= 2;
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 0.5, 0.5);
        imageSize.width *= 0.5;
        imageSize.height *= 0.5;
    }

    switch(pixelFormat) {       
        case kGLTexturePixelFormat_RGBA8888:
            colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
            data = malloc(height * width * 4);
            context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
            CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
            break;
        case kGLTexturePixelFormat_RGB565:
            colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
            data = malloc(height * width * 4);
            context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
            CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
            break;

        case kGLTexturePixelFormat_A8:
            data = malloc(height * width);
            context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height, 8, width, NULL, kCGImageAlphaOnly);
            break;              
        default:
            [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid pixel format"];
    }


    CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height));
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, height - imageSize.height);

    if(!CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(transform))
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);

    //Convert "RRRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAA" to "RRRRRGGGGGGBBBBB"
    if(pixelFormat == kGLTexturePixelFormat_RGB565) {
        tempData = malloc(height * width * 2);
        inPixel32 = (unsigned int*)data;
        outPixel16 = (unsigned short*)tempData;
        for(i = 0; i < width * height; ++i, ++inPixel32)
            *outPixel16++ = ((((*inPixel32 >> 0) & 0xFF) >> 3) << 11) | ((((*inPixel32 >> 8) & 0xFF) >> 2) << 5) | ((((*inPixel32 >> 16) & 0xFF) >> 3) << 0);
        free(data);
        data = tempData;

    }

    self = [self initWithData:data pixelFormat:pixelFormat pixelsWide:width pixelsHigh:height contentSize:imageSize];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    free(data); 

    return self;
}
```

Step 2 - bind and load texture:

```
- (id) initWithData:(const void*)data pixelFormat:(GLTexturePixelFormat)pixelFormat pixelsWide:(NSUInteger)width pixelsHigh:(NSUInteger)height contentSize:(CGSize)size
{
    GLint saveName;
    if((self = [super init])) {
        glGenTextures(1, &_name); //get a new texture id.  _name increases as more textures are loaded
        glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D, &saveName); //generally, saveName==1.  gets existing bound texture, so we can restore it after load.
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _name); //start working with our new texture id
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);  //added by ijames

       //associate pixel data with the texture id.
        switch(pixelFormat) {
            case kGLTexturePixelFormat_RGBA8888:
                glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
                break;
            case kGLTexturePixelFormat_RGB565:
                glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, data);
                break;
            case kGLTexturePixelFormat_A8:
                glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, width, height, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
                break;
            default:
                [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@""];

        }

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, saveName); //restore the previous texture binding.

        //NSLog(@"name %d, savename %d", _name, saveName);

        _size = size;
        _width = width;
        _height = height;
        _format = pixelFormat;
        _maxS = size.width / (float)width;
        _maxT = size.height / (float)height;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Do you see anything horribly wrong? Have any of you run into this problem before?  Where on earth is this phantom memory coming from?

Thanks for your time and thoughts!

**EDIT 1:**

I just added some lines to `initWithImage:` immediately before the call to `initWithData:` to convert any RGBA8888 textures to RGBA4444 on the fly when being loaded, just to see what would happen and how bad the graphics hit would be. The result was that the real memory usage decreased by almost 2x.  That means that wherever the mystery doubling is happening, it happens in or after the `initWithData:` step. Thanks again for you thoughts!

**EDIT 2:**

To answer one of the comments - here is how `initWithImage:` is called (this is the only place it happens - from a `ResourceManager` class that manages a cache for textures) :

```
//NOTE: 'texture' and '_textures' are declared earlier...

//if the texture doesn't already exist, create it and add it to the cache
NSString * fullPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: fileName];

UIImage * textureImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: fullPath];
texture = [[GLTexture alloc] initWithImage: textureImg];  //here's the call
[textureImg release];

[_textures setValue: texture forKey: fileName];
return [texture autorelease];
```

Comment: How do you obtain the UIImage, with `-imageNamed:`?  Is it possible that a bitmap representation of the image is being cached behind the scenes?

Comment: Hi Brad - yep, I read about the `UIImage::imageNamed:` caching ordeal, and so I'm using `initWithContentsOfFile:` instead.  Added an edit to clarify this in the question.  Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if you ran the Allocations instrument against this application, and did heap shots before and after your texture creation (repeated a few times to be sure), if it would show an accumulated object or something else in memory.  That might provide a clue as to what else could be using memory here.

Comment: Ran Allocations, but couldn't see anything more than a few K coming up, which was normal considering the things getting allocated that needed to get allocated.  I read that there's a bug with IOS 4.2+ where memory gets allocated for mipmaps even when you have mipmapping turned off.  That should only bring in about 40% increase, instead of a full 100%.  Anyway, it could be a start.

Comment: Yeah, I have heard of mipmapping adding to the memory consumption of textures.  I recall someone even mentioning that it almost doubled his memory usage when he wasn't careful with it.  Maybe you could manually disable mipmapping using `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_FALSE);`

Comment: A good idea - I implemented the manual kill mipmapping right after the other two `glTexParameteri()` calls in `initWithData:`.  No impact on memory usage though. Through reducing bit depth on some of my textures and other optimizations I've gotten to within "safe" running limits, but it's still twice as much memory as this thing should be using, and it would be way nice to get that back. Anyway, thanks for your thoughts and efforts.  If you have any insights, let me know, and if I find anything else out, I'll post it here!